# How would you write a "constructor"

Tags: javascript

I have been playing around with the concept of "factory functions" so consider:

```
var HelloWorld = function() {

    return  {
       hello: function() { console.log('hi'); }
    }
}
```

Which as we know is instantiated as: `var helloWorld = HelloWorld();` Would the "constructor" of such a function be the function it's self? And is there any way I could just do: `HelloWorld.hello()` instead of "instantiating it" like a class? Or is that a whole other concept?

Comment: [Constructor has a specific meaning in JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.4), and it has nothing to do with creating objects via factory functions (constructor functions are invoked with [the new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new))..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at following code:

```
var HelloWorldFactory = function(text) {
    return  {
       hello: function() { console.log(text); }
    }
};
var HelloWorld = {
  hello: function() { console.log('hi2'); }
};
var helloWorld = HelloWorldFactory('hi');
helloWorld.hello();
HelloWorld.hello();
```

as @Quentin mentioned in comment by calling `HelloWorldFactory('hi');` you are not calling js constructor but just a function which returns an object.

Doing `HelloWorld.hello();` is a different concept because you just use aleardy defined object(it can be created via factory or just defined in code)

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are returning an object literal with a function property. You could have returned directly a function as well. But at the end this is the factory pattern and created functions' constructor is the `Function` function not the `HelloWorld` function's prototype as it would be the case with constructors.

Functions are pure objects in JS. You can treat them just like objects. So do whatever you like to do with them.

```
function HelloWorld(){};

     HelloWorld.thank = function(){console.log("thanks")};
   HelloWorld.message = "hello";
HelloWorld.sayMessage = function(){console.log(HelloWorld.message)};
```

However constructor functions are slightly different. They are invoked with the `new` keyword and as i have mentioned above they assign their own prototype to the created object. It's one of the most complicated parts of JS. I have seen many people thinking `new` is useless, better be avoided and `Object.create()` should be preferred instead but it's not the case. There are times constructor functions are very useful since you can establish amazing prototypical relationships during the construction time.